# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'QueryInstance'

Tags: python, tinydb

I am trying to have a login system where user input will be crosschecked with tinydb's json file. I managed to get the registration working but when I try logging in I got this error.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'QueryInstance'

I tried removing password verification and it worked. Not entirely sure the reason behind it. Would be great if I can receive some guidance as to what went wrong. Thanks!

```
def login():
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
    User = Query()
    if(db.search(User.username == username) & (User.password == password)):
        print("Login Successful!")
        loggedInScreen()
    else:
        print("Incorrect Username or Password")
        login()
```

Comment: I don't know the library but you might wanna replace `&` with `and`. `&` is the logical bitwise operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been `and` not `&`. The operand `and` will check both the conditions that you are trying to validate whereas `&` does a bitwise AND and it doesn't like the types of data provided for the `bitwise` AND, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! When I was reading through the docs for tinydb it said to use &.

Answer (score 0):

`&` in Python is logical bitwise operator not the conditional operator, so replacing `&` with `and` should get it to work